# Get record from list based values from another list

Tags: c#, linq

I've two lists declared and filled in this way:

```
List<MyType> list1 = new List<MyType>();
List<MyType> list2 = new List<MyType>();

list1.Add(new MyType() { PropertyA = "Value1", PropertyB = "00" });
list1.Add(new MyType() { PropertyA = "Value1", PropertyB = "06" });
list1.Add(new MyType() { PropertyA = "Value1", PropertyB = "08" });
list1.Add(new MyType() { PropertyA = "Value1", PropertyB = "11" });
list1.Add(new MyType() { PropertyA = "Value1", PropertyB = "12" });
list1.Add(new MyType() { PropertyA = "Value2", PropertyB = "00" });
list1.Add(new MyType() { PropertyA = "Value2", PropertyB = "06" });
list1.Add(new MyType() { PropertyA = "Value2", PropertyB = "09" });
list1.Add(new MyType() { PropertyA = "Value2", PropertyB = "11" });
list1.Add(new MyType() { PropertyA = "Value2", PropertyB = "13" });
list1.Add(new MyType() { PropertyA = "Value2", PropertyB = "14" });
list1.Add(new MyType() { PropertyA = "Value3", PropertyB = "09" });
list1.Add(new MyType() { PropertyA = "Value3", PropertyB = "10" });
list1.Add(new MyType() { PropertyA = "Value3", PropertyB = "11" });
list1.Add(new MyType() { PropertyA = "Value3", PropertyB = "12" });
list1.Add(new MyType() { PropertyA = "Value3", PropertyB = "13" });
list1.Add(new MyType() { PropertyA = "Value3", PropertyB = "14" });

list2.Add(new MyType() { PropertyA = "Value1" });
list2.Add(new MyType() { PropertyA = "Value2" });
list2.Add(new MyType() { PropertyA = "Value3" });
```

My goal is to get, using LINQ in C#, from the **list1** the only record with PropertyB which is present in all elements that have **list2.PropertyA == list1.PropertyA**.

In my example, I've to get this value: **PropertyB = "11"**

How can i get this value?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: In your example, you get 14 too

Comment: @CaiusJard: Yes, sorry wrong example. I've corrected it. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Provided that the lists are distinct and are exactly as in the question (listA PropertyA contains only things in listB, not Value4 etc), group the listA by propertyB and look for groupings that have listB.Count number of values

For example

```
var r = list1.GroupBy(a => a.PropertyB)
  .Where(g => g.Count() == listB.Count)
  .Select(g => g.Key);
```

If listA might contain PropertyA like Value4 which is not a member of ListB it's a bit more involved. Turning listB into a HashSet makes things easier

```
var hash2 = list2.Select(s => s.PropertyA).ToHashSet();
var r = list1.GroupBy(a => a.PropertyB, a => a.PropertyA)
  .Where(g => hash2.SetEquals(g))
  .Select(g => g.Key);
```